# Creating an interactive iframe with an excel document

Tags: html, excel

I am trying to create an iframe that contains an interactive excel file. 
My problem is that I can't seem to display the excel within the iframe, it is just blank.

When the code runs however, it will prompt you to open the excel file itself. I understand that the code below is letting me select an excel file and then open it when the page is open, however without having to save the excel file as a *webpage*, is there a way to display an interactive excel book within an iframe?

```
<html>
<head>
</head> 
<iframe src="excel.xlsx"></iframe>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: The blank issue]

Comment: where? why? how? You can't just put a filename in a tag and "wish" that whatever random browser can figure out **where** the file is, what **type** of file it is, and what you want to **do** with it.   *I wish... `<iframe src="win lottery">`*  :-)  Have you done some research?  If so, what did you find out?

Comment: I have researched the question itself and have come to many dead ends. I am drawing closer and closer to the conclusion that I am not able to do such a thing. This site was my last hope for an answer.

Comment: @ashleedawg, Web Development would be sweet if your iframe code worked lol

Comment: Perhaps you're being too vague on your searches, as well as here.  "`HTML`" for example.  No other we coding languages involved?  What are you planning on *doing* with this?  What kind of data will be in the workbook?  Or, will it be different workbooks?  Who's going to see this?  Internal/external?  How are they going to be interacting with it?  What's the end goal? Are they any alternatives?  Why an iFrame?  What about Excel's built-in web functionality?  A little background goes a long way. Perhaps you need to figure out the details of the plan before pursuing an answer?

Comment: I am creating a training "portal" and wanted to have some sort of excel interactivity on the page itself without having to open an excel file or do any sort of vba coding. I appreciate your help with my journey for this hypothetical-answer!